# Generate 3 random lists and create another one with the sum of their elements

Tags: python, list, matrix

I want to create a NxN matrix (represented as lists of lists), where the first n-1 columns have random numbers in the range 1 to 10, and the last column contains the result of adding the numbers in previous commons.

```
import random
randomlist1 = []
for i in range(1,10):
    n = random.randint(1,100)
    randomlist1.append(n)
print(randomlist1)

randomlist2 = []
for i in range(1,10):
    n = random.randint(1,100)
    randomlist2.append(n)
print(randomlist2)

randomlist3 = []
for i in range(1,10):
    n = random.randint(1,100)
    randomlist3.append(n)
print(randomlist3)

# I have problems here

lists_of_lists = [sum(x) for x in (randomlist1, randomlist2,randomlist3)]
[sum(x) for x in zip(*lists_of_lists)]
print(lists_of_lists)
```

Comment: So you say the output is supposed to have shape NxN and you also say you would like 3 random lists (which in your code contain 9 elements each). It is not clear to me what your output is supposed to look like.

Comment: The final output is a matrix of 4x4. Three first columns are the lists (randomlist1, randomlist2 and randomlist3). The 4th column is the sum of those lists, element by element. Let me know if you need further clarification. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those three lists in your code contain 9 elements so the matrix would have shape 9x4, and also the random integers in the code are in the range 1 to 100 (inclusive) rather than 1 to 10 (inclusive)

Answer (score 1):

Your question calls for a few comments:

- the title does not correspond to the question, and the code matches the title, not the question;
- the rows `randomlist1` , `randomlist1` , `randomlist1`  are not in a matrix;
- the final value is not a square matrix;
- You write *"the columns have random numbers in the range of 1 to 10"* but your code `randint(1,100)` creates numbers in the range [1..100].

#### Solution to the question

```
import random 
N = 5

# create a N by N-1 matrix of random integers
matrix = [[random.randint(1, 10) for j in  range(N-1)] for i in range(N)]
print(f"{N} by {N-1} matrix:\n{matrix}")

# add a  column as sum of the previous ones
for line in matrix:
    line.append(sum(line))
print(f"{N} by {N} matrix with the last column as sum of the previous ones:\n{matrix}")
```

Ouput:

```
5 by 4 matrix:
[[7, 10, 5, 6], [4, 10, 9, 3], [5, 5, 4, 9], [10, 7, 2, 4], [8, 8, 5, 3]]
5 by 5 matrix with the last column as sum of the previous ones:
[[7, 10, 5, 6, 28], [4, 10, 9, 3, 26], [5, 5, 4, 9, 23], [10, 7, 2, 4, 23], [8, 8, 5, 3, 24]]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC try with numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1) # just for demo purposes 
# lists comprehensions to create your 3 lists inside a list
lsts = [np.random.randint(1,100, 10).tolist() for i in range(3)]
np.sum(lsts, axis=0) 
# array([145, 100, 131, 105, 215, 115, 194, 247, 116,  45])
```

lsts

```
[[38, 13, 73, 10, 76, 6, 80, 65, 17, 2],
 [77, 72, 7, 26, 51, 21, 19, 85, 12, 29],
 [30, 15, 51, 69, 88, 88, 95, 97, 87, 14]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @It_is_Chris answer, I propose this as a numpy only implementation, without using lists:

```
np.random.seed(1)

final_shape = (3, 10)
lsts = np.random.randint(1, 100, np.prod(final_shape)).reshape(final_shape)
lstsum = np.sum(lsts, axis=0)
```